# How to update mulitple rows value in single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, case

Hi I have a one table called as title its have id and date field, now id is have da but date value is Present 0000-00-00 00:00:00.
Now i want to update (2019-11-01 00:00:00) multiple rows based on id

My Present Table

[image]

I want result

[image]

Comment: How do you decide which date should be affected to each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a conditional update based on `jtm_id`:

```
update title 
set jtm_cdatetime = case jtm_id
    when 2 then '2017-10-10'
    when 3 then '2017-10-11'
    when 4 then '2017-10-10'
    when 5 then '2017-10-02'
    when 7 then '2017-10-12'
end
where jtm_cdatetime is null
```